# How to set lebel right allinged in columlayout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am very new in react js and using `matrial core UI`. Here what i found is whenever i am using `columnlayout` with some `xs` value then the component inside the column is left allinged.

For bringing it right i need to increase xs which is not fitting correct. Is there any way I can place my tag element inside column layout to right allinged.  Any css heck ?

My Code

```
<Columnlayout xs{1} item>
    <InputLabel>Some Text</InputLabel>
</Columnlayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the api helper of Material-ui

```
<Columnlayout xs{1} item justify="flex-end">
    <InputLabel>Some Text</InputLabel>
</Columnlayout>
```

Here is a link for all the customization
https://material-ui.com/api/grid/